# Use IF statement within update statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, sql-update

In the following peace of code, I'm trying to use update value of table's col according to specific condition. but the syntax is not correct !. Is there an idea to  update tables according a conditions ?

```
UPDATE table SET col=
 IF (condition)
value1
 ELSE
value2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case expression:

```
UPDATE table SET col=
 case when (condition) then value1
 ELSE value2
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using case..when..then

```
UPDATE table  
SET col = CASE  
              WHEN condition1 THEN value1 
              WHEN condition2 THEN value2 
              WHEN condition3 THEN value3 
              ELSE value4
          END
```